# Understanding $\mathbb{P}^2$ and rational Bézier curves

Tags: projective-geometry, bezier-curve, homogeneous-spaces

I've never taken a projective geometry course, and I'm trying to understand the real projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ and its description using homogeneous coordinates, and how these relate to rational Bézier curves.

I understand that the elements of $\mathbb{P}^2$ can be identified with lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Also (equivalently) elements of $\mathbb{P}^2$ can be described by homogeneous coordinates of the form $[x:y:z]$ where two coordinate triples are regarded as equal if their elements are proportional (a nice simple equivalence relationship). All good so far.

Now let's look at how homogeneous coordinates are typically used with 2D rational Bézier curves. Given $n+1$ 2D points $P_0, \ldots, P_n$ and $n+1$ weights $w_0, \ldots, w_n$, we can define a rational Bezier curve
$$
C(t) = \frac{\sum \phi_i(t)w_iP_i}{\sum \phi_i(t)w_i}
$$
where the $\phi_i$ are Bernstein polynomials of degree $n$. Fine, no problem.

But then people suggest that we should take the point $P_i = (x_i, y_i)$ and the weight $w_i$
and combine them to get an element of $\mathbb{P}^2$, like this: $\overline{P}_i = [w_ix_i:w_iy_i: w_i]$. Having done this, we can now think about a somehow related Bézier curve:
$$
\overline{C}(t) = \sum \phi_i(t)\overline{P}_i
$$
This makes us happy because $\overline{C}(t)$ looks like a **polynomial** curve, rather than a rational one, so we're back to more familiar territory.

But this doesn't make sense to me. The right-hand side of the last equation does additions
and scalar multiplications of elements of $\mathbb{P}^2$, but what do these mean?

So, in short, my questions are **what do addition and scalar multiplication mean in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (if anything). Is it a vector space? If not, what kind of algebraic structure is it?**

Comment: As with any group action, you can work in the original space and look at invariant things. Take the circle $x^2+y^2-1=0.$ It is given as $(x,y)=(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2}).$ As in your case, the denominator is the same, and we can in ${\Bbb P}^2$ write $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$ and $(x:y:z)=(1-t^2:2t:1+t^2),$ we can even go further and homogenize the parametrization: $(x:y:z)=(s^2-t^2:2st:s^2+t^2),$ where $s,t$ are the homogeneous coordinates of ${\Bbb P}^1.$ Note that this makes sense in space as the cone as a surface, and whole lines through the origin are ready to be considered as points.

Comment: Thanks. That all makes sense. But what about $(x : y:z) = (1:0:1) + t(0:2:0) +t^2(-1:0:1)$. Is that valid? Does $\mathbb{P}^2$ have addition and scalar multiplication operations?

Comment: Sure, it's just (in space) $(x, y, z) = (1-t^2, 2t, 1+t^2)$ a parabola. It has one representative of each line through the origin of the cone, and as such it gives the curve in ${\Bbb P}^2.$ It's just cleaner to have the whole cone ($s$ and all), and that completes the picture including the missing point as well. Work in the vector space ${\Bbb R}^3,$ and just make sure it respects taking one point of each line through the origin, or the ${\Bbb R}^*$-action.

Comment: So, are you saying that, in $\mathbb{P}^2$, it’s true that $(1:0:1)+t(0:2:0)+t^2(−1:0:1) = (1-t^2: 2t : 1+t^2)$?  Certainly that’s true if we regard each triple as an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but in $\mathbb{P}^2$??

Comment: Also, suppose I replace $(1:0:1)$ by $(7:0:7)$. Those are equal in $\mathbb{P}^2$, right, but I get a very different rational curve.

Comment: Don't do that then. Work in ${\Bbb R}^3,$ and make sure you're respecting the group action taking lines through the origin to points in ${\Bbb P}^2.$ You'll get the intuition after a while.